# Suma en arreglos en php

Tags: php, mysql

Estoy tratando de sumar un serie de arreglos que obtengo de mi base de datos.

Quiero realizar una función que haga otro array donde sume el valor total con las fechas que coincidan entre sí, y las que no, iterarlas dentro del **array** de igual forma

Posterior a ello los pasare por ajax y luego haré una gráfica a partir de esos datos con chart.js

`Código a iterar`

```
array (7){

[0]=>array(2){
 
 ["total"] => "20",
 
 ["fecha"]=> "2021-08-15"
}

[1]=>array(2){
 
 ["total"] => "262",

 ["fecha"]=> "2021-08-15"
}

[2]=>array(2){
 
 ["total"] => "342",
 
 ["fecha"]=> "2021-08-15"
}

[3]=>array(2){
 
 ["total"] => "84",
 
 ["fecha"]=> "2021-08-16"
}

[4]=>array(2){
 
 ["total"] => "247",
 
 ["fecha"]=> "2021-08-16"
}

[5]=>array(2){
 
 ["total"] => "247",
 
 ["fecha"]=> "2021-08-17"
}

[6]=>array(2){
 
 ["total"] => "657",
 
 ["fecha"]=> "2021-08-18"
}
}
```

Comment: La pregunta no es muy clara. Y, ¿por qué no traes ya los datos sumados desde la consulta SQL, evitando así tener que manipularlos DE NUEVO, con un consiguiente impacto en el rendimiento del código?

Comment: Intentaré usar esa función muchísimas gracias

Answer (score 0):

Para hacerlo con php simplemente recorres el arreglo con datos, creas un arreglo vacío como salida y utilizas la fecha como key para el nuevo array. Si la clave ya existe simplemente sumas el valor, si la clave no existe la creas e igualas al valor del elemento en cuestión.

```
<?php
    $data = [
        ["total" => 100 , "fecha" => "2021-08-15"],   
        ["total" => 80 , "fecha" => "2021-08-15"], 
        ["total" => 50 , "fecha" => "2021-08-16"]
    ];
    
    
    function sum($elements){
        $output = array();
        foreach($elements as $element){
            $key = $element["fecha"];
            if(isset($output[$key])){
                $output[$key] += $element["total"];
            }else {
                $output[$key] = $element["total"];
            }
        }
        return $output;
    }
    
    print_r(sum($data));
```

Coincido con los comentarios, esto es más optimo hacerlo a nivel de SQL. Dado que no es el foco de la pregunta hacerlo con SQL, dejaré una sentencia referencial para que la adaptes.

```
SELECT sum(total) as total, fecha FROM your_table GROUP BY fecha
```

> Cuando trabajas con agrupación solo podrás aplicar funciones de grupo y consultar por columnas que están siendo agrupadas luego de la clausula group by. Si necesitas agregar más columnas en tu consulta, deberás agregarlas también en el group by para que la consulta funcione correctamente.